# Creating a "next" button that switches the content of a TextView

Tags: android

I have a popup text view with a next button and onClick I would like to switch the content.
This is what I tried ...cant get it to work. The error im getting is type mismatch cannot convert from void to int

```
    package com.jibushi;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class LessonsShell extends Activity{
    private static final int MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP=7;
    private static final long TIME_DELAY=1000;//1 seconds
    private View view;
    private Button nextButton;
    private Button skipButton;
    private TextView nextSwitch;
    private int tutStrings;
    private int tutStrings2;
    private int tutStrings3;
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          switch(msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP:
               view();
               break;
           }
       };
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.lessons);
        //this will send a message to the handler to display the popup after 1 seconds.
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP,TIME_DELAY);

        nextSwitch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsDialog);
        tutStrings = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
        tutStrings2 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction2); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
        tutStrings3 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction3); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int

        this.nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case tutStrings:
                    nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction2);
                    break;

                    case tutStrings2:
                    nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction3);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void view() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lessons_bg);
     view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.lessons_dialog,                 null);
     parent.addView(view);
    }

    public Button getSkipButton() {
        return skipButton;
    }

    public void setSkipButton(Button skipButton) {
        this.skipButton = skipButton;
        skipButton.findViewById(R.id.skip_button);


    }

    public Button getNextButton() {
        return nextButton;
    }

    public void setNextButton(Button nextButton) {
        this.nextButton = nextButton;
        nextButton.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    }


    }
```

Yeah, lack of research. Didn't know about string arrays...finally got it!

```
    package com.jibushi;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class LessonsShell extends Activity{
    private static final int MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP=7;
    private static final long TIME_DELAY=1000;//1 seconds
    private View view;

    private int count = 0;
    private TextView lessonsDialog;
    private String[] lessonDialogString;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          switch(msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP:
               view();
               break;
           }
       };
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.lessons);
    //this will send a message to the handler to display the popup after 1 seconds.
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP,TIME_DELAY);

    }

    private void view() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lessons_bg);
     view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.lessons_dialog,                 null);
     parent.addView(view);

     lessonsDialog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsDialog);

     Resources res = getResources();
     myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.lessons_dialog_array); 

     Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
     nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             if (count < lessonDialogString.length) {
                 lessonsDialog.setText(lessonDialogString[count]);
                 count++;
             }
         }
     });

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, lack of research on my part. Used string-array.. works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

I don't know what you are trying to do here:

```
nextSwitch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lessonsDialog);
tutStrings = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
tutStrings2 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction2); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
tutStrings3 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction3); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
```

the `TextView.setText(String)` does not return a value so these lines don't make any sense.  Are you trying to save the strings themselves?

Also your `onClick` method has problems as well. The `View` that is passed to `onClick` is the actual `view` that was clicked which in this case will be the `nextButton`. In your code you are switching on the undefined ints and not the id's of the different views in your activity.

Instead do something like this:

```
void onClick(View v){

switch(v.getId()){
   case R.id.next_button:
        setTextViewNextString();
   break;
   case R.id.prev_button:
        setTextViewPrevString();
}
```

Then you simply define the `setTextViewNextString()` and `setTextViewPrevString()` methods

Answer (score 0):

The method setText returns void:

> public final **void** setText (int resid)

(from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

You cannot assign void to int variables. These lines

```
tutStrings = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
tutStrings2 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction2); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
tutStrings3 = nextSwitch.setText(R.string.lessons_introduction3); //type mismatch cannot convert from void to int
```

are wrong.

I think you can solve your problem in this way:

1) Save the IDs in your private variables:

```
tutStrings = R.string.lessons_introduction;
tutStrings2 = R.string.lessons_introduction2;
tutStrings3 = R.string.lessons_introduction3;
```

2) Save the strings, getting them from resources:

```
private String s1, s2, s3;

...

s1 = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction);
s2 = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction2);
s3 = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction3);
```

3) Now you can use the onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case tutStrings:
        nextSwitch.setText(s2);
        break;

    case tutStrings2:
        nextSwitch.setText(s3);
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your Code like this:

```
tutStrings = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction);
tutStrings2 = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction2); 
tutStrings3 = this.getString(R.string.lessons_introduction3);
```

Please Note: In `onClick` you have to replace `this` with the name of your class e.g. `Myclass.getString` or just remove the `this.`

Comment: setText method returns null... How can you assign null values to int variables?

Comment: Sry just c&p your code there and was just looking at the setTextMethod not on your other errors.